# Does my MacBook DisplayPort support video input?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, displayport, hdmi

I have been reading through all these resources [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) and [here](http://www.displayport.org/faq/), but I couldn't find an answer.

My question is simply: can the DisplayPort on a MacBook take a video input source?

More Details:

I have:

1. Macbook Pro Model 6,2 (Mid-2010) that has a DisplayPort output
2. A camcorder that has HDMI output and NO FireWire outputs.
3. A HDMI to DisplayPort adapter.

I want to know if its possible to use my camcorder like a webcam, i.e, to capture live video for the purpose of streaming. As a primary test, I should be able to connect the camcorder and do a capture using iMovie.

Would this be possible? I am pretty sure input through USB won't work. And from what I have seen there is no easy way to convert the HDMI video stream into FireWire. So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not, I fear: the DisplayPort is an output only.

Comment: This is true, mini display port does not support video in.

Answer (score 0):

So if the DisplayPort does not support input, how then does the built-in iSight camera on the external monitor work so well through the DisplayPort connection?

Comment: If you are not answering the question you should consider posting your own question or write a comment.

Comment: " So if the DisplayPort does not support input, how then does the built-in iSight camera on the external monitor work so well through the DisplayPort connection? "  The answer is that it's not using DisplayPort for video input.  Apple monitors with DisplayPort video input had a separate USB cable for the camera.  Apple monitors with Thunderbolt used the bidirectional communication on that cable for the camera.  There is a provision in the DP 1.2 spec for USB 2.0 on the AUX channel for things like a camera but I've yet to see this used this way.